# Incidence algebra zeta and mobius matrix?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, mobius-inversion

Trying to follow the notes for understanding how to compute the zeta and mobius matrices from a graph. The graph is

[image]

Zeta matrix entries defined by

$\zeta(a,b)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & if \quad a \nleqslant b \\
1 &  if \quad a \leq b \\ 
\end{matrix}\right.$

which gives zeta matrix $Z$ for rows and columns in order of $a,b,c,d$ (not sure how to get this, following containment $a \prec b \prec d$. This definition doesn't say anything about containment either.

$$Z=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

For the Mobius matrix $M$, it is defined again without containment. The mobius function is defined

$$\mu(a,b)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & if \quad a = b \\
0 & if \quad a \nleqslant b \\
-\sum_{c:a \leq c \leq b}\mu(a,c) & if \quad a < b \\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

It is clear that $ZM=I$, but i'm not sure how you get to containment/set relations from these numerical relations on the graph?

Comment: (1) The matrix $Z$ should have $1$ in the last entries of the second and third rows.  Then your $M$ will be its inverse. (2) I assume your graph is intended to be a Hasse diagram, thus defining an order relation on $\{a,b,c,d\}$. (3) I have no idea what you mean by "containment", since that word is only in your question, not the quoted material. (4) Likewise for "set relations" and "numerical relations".